# kafka consumer describe command timeout when querying for all groups but returning results for single group

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka consumer describe command is throwing timeout exception when querying for all groups but returning results for a single group. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `kafka-consumer-groups` by itself and it'll show all valid options

These include `--timeout` and `--command-config` where you can give timeout properties to the request